# Setting background color for a UILabel?

Tags: swift

I know this will probably be the simplest question on stack overflow today but here it is. I am trying to set a background color for a UILabel. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func chemistryButton0(sender: UIButton){
    if chemistryButton0?.backgroundColor == UIColor(red: 212, green: 142, blue: 69) {
        let detailBackgroundColor.backgroundColor == UIColor(red: 212, green: 142, blue: 69)
    }
}
```

There is an error on the backgroundColor statement but it says the statements should be separated.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude. When a thing already exists you don't say `let`.

Comment: Haha. I'm so dumb. Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

the line should be

```
detailBackgroundColor.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 212, green: 142, blue: 69)
```

"let" is only necessary when declaring a new constant, and "==" is a comparison operator, whereas "=" sets the value

Answer (score 0):

I think you left an `alpha` there, and you code should be

```
detailBackgroundColor.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 212, green: 142, blue: 69, alpha:  0)
```